# CakePHP 2.6: Getting PDO Exception on calling model function in controller

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.6

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getStateCity' at line 1

Following code is working:

$

```
response['data'] =  $this->StateZip->find('first', array(
                                'fields' => array('StateZip.state', 'StateZip.city', 'StateZip.zip'),
                                'conditions' => array('StateZip.zip' => $zip)));
```

However same is not working if called  through model function

```
 $response['data'] = $this->StateZip->getStateCity($zip);
```

Content of getStateCity is

```
public function getStateCity($zip){
        $response = array('status'=>'error','data'=>'');

        $data = $this->find('first', array(
                'fields' => array('StateZip.state', 'StateZip.city', 'StateZip.zip'),
                'conditions' => array('StateZip.zip' => $zip)
        ));

        return $data;
    }
```

Any help and suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Is `$this->StateZip` really the type that you think it is when you try to call your function? It looks like maybe you're trying to call that on a table object of a different class than where you've actually implemented the function.

Comment: StateZip is model defined and included as $uses = array('StateZip',<other models>)

Comment: That should work, but have you checked 100% for sure with something like `pr(get_class($this->StateZip));`?

Comment: This is returning ``AppModel``. Is this correct?

Comment: If I do ` try {
                            $this->loadModel('StateZip');
                        echo "model is loaded";
                        } catch(MissingModelException $e) {
                        // Model not found!             
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                        }         
`

This is also showing 'model is loaded'

Comment: Not sure though.... Can it happen because of some php extension is missing or something?

Comment: It is failing to find your model class, and falling back to a default skeleton version. That's a common problem on here, you should be able to find lots of answers. If you can't, I'll see what I can dig up tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Greg! You are correct. model files were present in sub-directory of Model. I moved one level-up and it started working. There is path mentioned in bootstrap.php but looks like somehow that is not getting used. Thanks once again!